# Microsoft Edge не работает с кириллическими доменами?

Tags: vkontakte-api, microsoft-edge

Работая с api ВКонтакте на кириллическом домене, обнаружил в Microsoft Edge ошибку:

> Источник [http://мой-сайт.рф](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84) не найден в заголовке
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Проверил ответ запроса от ВКонтакте и обнаружил, что ВКонтакте правильно обрабатывает домен в punycode, а вот Edge в каких-то кракозябрах и сравнивая punycode со своим закорючками, ругается на то, что домен, с которого осуществляется запрос, и домен, который его принимает, не идентичны. Я понимаю, что писать в поддержку Edge бесполезно, такие баги не фиксят годами, но, вероятно, есть какое-то решение? Возможно ли на кириллическом домене работать с клиентским api ВКонтакте в браузере Microsoft Edge?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну если только напистаь патч под него) которые будет выполнять проверки соответсующие)

Comment: А вы бы всё же направили багрепорт. А то так никогда и не пофиксят.

Comment: А почему бы не представиться тем сайтом, который на скриншоте в нижнем овале?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что когда-то уже прогнулись под IE и он решил, что ему всё можно.</сарказм> На самом деле этот заголовок заполняется браузером, а не клиентским кодом. CORS так работает.

Comment: @D-side, заголовок-то да. Но вот то что в нём написано - это адрес сайта для тех, кто не умеет кириллицу. Например, Spark покажет такой адрес. Т. е. по нему тоже можно открыть страницу.

Comment: @D-side `http://xn----7sbayvhepxaf.xn--p1ai` = `http://массаж-омск.рф`. Кстати, хром отображает кириллический вариант, но в буфер обмена копирует первый.

Comment: @Qwertiy nu-uh, то не Origin, а ACAO. Насколько я понимаю, в панели управления введён домен as-is, кириллицей, ВК правильно его обработал и просит в punycode, а Edge забарахлил и утверждает, что у него Origin кириллица с поехавшей кодировкой. Я не вижу тут сходу способов починки пользователем.

Comment: @D-side, а если сделать `window.location.href = "http://xn----7sbayvhepxaf.xn--p1ai"`?

Comment: @Qwertiy надо пробовать. Может и прокатит, а может браузер опознает punycode, автоматически вывернет урл в кириллицу и вуаля, всё как было .-.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь! Изменения window.location.href приводят к перезагрузке страницы. А если вводить в адресную строку punicode или кириллицу, Origin от этого не изменится. Патч тоже не подойдет, так как это приложение для массовой аудитории. Проблему я все же решил, но другим путем, пришлось создать собственный метод обращения к vk api, а как известно проверка требуется для методов авторизации вконтакте, мне авторизация в приложении не нужна.